# Making the rails console output a little more pretty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

a rails console output looks like this:

```
User.all
=> [#<User id: 1, name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com",
created_at: "2011-12-05 00:57:46", updated_at: "2011-12-05 00:57:46">,
#<User id: 2, name: "A Nother", email: "another@example.org", created_at:
"2011-12-05 01:05:24", updated_at: "2011-12-05 01:05:24">]
```

I was wondering if there is command that can make it easier to read?  for example there was a *.pretty* command in MongoDB console that was formatting the output a little more eye friendly. But not sure if there is something similar in Rails or not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Also you could use this incredible gem:

[Awesome Print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print)

Answer (score 76):

A bit more elegant shorthand:

```
y User.all
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest I've found as well as the nicest formatting of the output.

Comment: WOW !

I didn't know this, but it does the job ... and works in any project, no gem to add (it's part of the Kernel AFAIK) !!!

Perfect, Thanks !

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you

Comment: I don't know if it's just me but this is even worse than what the original problem was. Instead of getting all the records bunched together this gives me about 50 lines per record of mostly useless info.

Comment: @SteveCarey Indeed, from Rails v4 I think it prints everything. So if this doesn't work for you then try: `User.find_each { |u| y u.attributes }`.

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely better. For just a couple attributes on the same line something like this works well too User.find_each { |u| puts "#{u.id} #{u.name}" }

Comment: pp is better than y. I don't think people scroll down my answer if they prefer this one.

Answer (score 46):

I've been using `pp`. The pp stands for "pretty print." No Gem required.

On rails console try doing this:

```
pp User.all
```

You'll get each attributes and their value in the record display in a row instead a bundle of them if you simply do User.all.

Here's the documentation:

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html

I am using Rails 5.1.3 and ruby 2.4.1p111 and it came already installed in my project. If this don't work, I imagine you have to do `require 'pp'`.
I hope this helps.

Comment: This was the best answer for my project. Yaml formatted ruby objects IS NOT PRETTY PRINT.

Answer (score 30):

If you don't want to use a gem, here's the low rent version:

```
 puts User.all.to_yaml
```

Comment: great suggestion as it does not require dependencies

Answer (score 8):

You could try the awesome_print gem :
https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

Once installed, you can pretty print any object using :

```
ap User.all
```

Comment: Doesn't pretty print ActiveRecord for me. It does pretty print other containers, though.

Comment: @Anthony Alberto In github page https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print#awesome-print it says: NOTE: awesome_print v1.2.0 is the last release supporting Ruby versions prior to v1.9.3 and Rails versions prior to v3.0. The upcoming awesome_print v2.0 will require Ruby v1.9.3 or later and Rails v3.0 or later. This means that I can't use `awesome_print` in Rails 4 or 5?

Comment: @Lykos, this means that you can't use `awesome_print` **version 2.0** when using a Rails version below 3. You can use `awesome_print` with any Rails version, you just have to choose the appropriate version of `awesome_print` to match:  
a) If you are using Rails 3, 4, or 5, you should use `awesome_print v2.0`.  
b) If you are using Rails 1 or 2, you must use `awesome_print v1.2`.

Comment: awesome_print v1.8.0 seems to be latest as of today, and works fine with Rails 5.2.3 for me, including on User.all as noted above

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few options

#### yaml format (no dependencies)

```
y your_code
```

#### awesome_print

```
gem install awesome_print
```

Then in irb or pry

```
require 'awesome_print'
ap your_code
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `pry`

**Without pry:**

```
2.3.1 :001 > SupplierTerm.first
  SupplierTerm Load (39.4ms)  SELECT  "supplier_terms".* FROM "supplier_terms" ORDER BY "supplier_terms"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<SupplierTerm id: "1bc48081-402a-41d9-b6af-d783c28bb363", 
entity_id: "927b398f-2bbd-40cb-b668-eb284e26688d", uses_custom_terms: 
false, requires_credit_check: false, requires_identity_check: false, 
requires_guarantees: true, requires_trade_reference_check: true, 
minimum_guarantees: 1, minimum_trade_references: 1, trade_account_limit: 
20000, created_at: "2017-02-01 22:11:49", updated_at: "2017-02-01 
22:11:49", created_by_id: "2c314f8a-6d84-48c8-a963-75130e97f1a6", 
updated_by_id: "2c314f8a-6d84-48c8-a963-75130e97f1a6", questions: [], 
minimum_approvers: 1, excluded_sources: nil>
```

**With pry:**

```
2.3.1 :002 > pry
[1] pry(main)> SupplierTerm.first
  SupplierTerm Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "supplier_terms".* FROM "supplier_terms" ORDER BY "supplier_terms"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<SupplierTerm:0x007fb4e1feff40
 id: "1bc48081-402a-41d9-b6af-d783c28bb363",
 entity_id: "927b398f-2bbd-40cb-b668-eb284e26688d",
 uses_custom_terms: false,
 requires_credit_check: false,
 requires_identity_check: false,
 requires_guarantees: true,
 requires_trade_reference_check: true,
 minimum_guarantees: 1,
 minimum_trade_references: 1,
 trade_account_limit: 20000,
 created_at: Wed, 01 Feb 2017 22:11:49 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 01 Feb 2017 22:11:49 UTC +00:00,
 created_by_id: "2c314f8a-6d84-48c8-a963-75130e97f1a6",
 updated_by_id: "2c314f8a-6d84-48c8-a963-75130e97f1a6",
 questions: [],
 minimum_approvers: 1,
 excluded_sources: nil>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an awesome gem called [Jazz Hands](https://github.com/nixme/jazz_hands). Includes pry-based enhancements, hirb, and awesome_print in rails console.

P.S. You might want to use the fork [Jazz Fingers](https://github.com/plribeiro3000/jazz_fingers) to make it compatible with Ruby 2.1.2